# Get image local link from JSON and load it on html file

Tags: javascript, html, json, image

I have a JSON link that contains various information and a path to an image on the computer and I wanted to load that image into a div in html.
I already have code to fetch text from the JSON and put it in the html, but I can't put the image in the html

JSON link:
`http://192.168.1.67:1312/results.json`

JSON info:

```json
{"CasaFaltas":"5","CasaFaltas.Source":"C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\Carrega Play\\Scoreboard\\Faltas\\Falta0.png","CasaGolos":"10","Tempo":"2:56","VisitanteFaltas":"3","VisitanteGolos":"11"}
```

To go get the text, I have the code below.
However I don't know how to get the image to make it available in html
(however, if you have suggestions for improving my code, I'll gladly accept)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table class="TabelaTempo">
    <tr style="height:20px">
      <td style="width:340px"> </td>
      <td id="Tempo" style="width:85px; font-size:18px">20:00</td>
      <td style="width:44px"> </td>
      <td style="width:45px; font-size:18px">1ª P</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function $(a) {
      return document.getElementById(a)
    }

    function ajax(a, b, c) {
      c = new XMLHttpRequest;
      c.open('GET', a);
      c.onload = b;
      c.send()
    }

    function reloadData() {
      ajax('http://192.168.1.67:1312/results.json', updateText)
    };

    function updateText() {
      var db = JSON.parse(this.response);
      $("Tempo").innerHTML = db.Tempo;
      $("CasaGolos").innerHTML = db.CasaGolos;
      $("VisitanteGolos").innerHTML = db.VisitanteGolos;
      $("CasaFaltas").innerHTML = db.CasaFaltas;
      $("VisitanteFaltas").innerHTML = db.VisitanteFaltas;
      $("CasaFaltas.Source").innerHTML = db.CasaFaltas.Source;
    }
    window.setInterval(reloadData, 100);


    $('#i_file').change(function(event) {
      $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Make the JSON contain an `http://192.168.1.67:1312/...` path, instead of a `C:\...` path.

Comment: Also I see no XML in this question, why is it in the title?

Comment: Sorry @Tomalak, I already corrected the title.
About changing the path, I can't do it.
Just to put it in context:

Basically this (json link) is generated by an application (OCR Scoreborad), in which the function is to read a scoreboard of a futsal game (stream) and convert the data to OBS.

And the purpose of having an image is when it reads the number of fouls in the game (between 0 and 5), put an image to indicate the number of fouls, like this marked in yellow: https://imgur.com/a/1y1Mj1I

Comment: Actualmente ele tem um script que consoante o número de faltas devolve a localização da imagem, como está publicado no json:
{"CasaFaltas":"5","CasaFaltas.Source":"C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\Carrega Play\\Scoreboard\\Faltas\\Falta0.png","CasaGolos":"10","Tempo":"2:56","VisitanteFaltas":"3","VisitanteGolos":"11"}

Comment: What I need is that the HTML file I have, go to the JSON link and show the image that is indicated in the path.

For the part of fetching the texts (Number of goals and game time) it is already working well.

But I don't know how I can put an image in a div, based on the path that the Json is indicating.

Comment: From what I've read on the Scoreboard OCR homepage, [you have full control over its output](https://scoreboard-ocr.com/scripted_output).  But if you can't change the path in the JSON, change it in JavaScript before putting it into the `<img>` src. Overall, the URL for the image source needs look like the URL for the HTML page. Whether you open the HTML file directly (URL `file:///C:/.../bla.html`) or if you have a local webserver (URL `http://localhost/.../bla.html`) - manipulate the image path so that it matches.